# Mysql communications link failure from Talend mysqlinput commponet(backend code is Java)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, talend, mysql-error-1064

I use keepalive=10 in my JDBC connection string also and `wait_timeout` is set to `28800`.

Can you please help me with the following error?

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 12,053,926 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 12,053,926 milliseconds ago.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 12,053,926 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 12,053,926 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2596)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getUserName(DatabaseMetaData.java:7013)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Write failed)
```

Comment: The error indicates that you haven't used the connection for a very long time (more than three hours). Likely you have a maximum connection lifetime configured on the server that kills the connection.

Comment: how i will keep the connection active for so long . wait_timeout already defined  28800.